# cannot show the result of php file, help me

Tags: php, html, forms

I don't know why it cannot show the result. I have already put isset() Function on it, but the echo string is not come out.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" checked="true"> 
    <label id="r">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green">
    <label id="g">Green</label>

    <input type="button" name="add" value="Add">
    <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>


<?php
    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['colors'])) {
            $colorVal = $_POST['colors'];
            echo "$colorVal";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: remove "" from variable as  `echo $colorVal;` also change the button type  to  `submit`

Comment: If you checked one radio why do you control if variable $_POST['color'] is ISSET?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Its good to keep all checks on the server end. Also, if someone tries to remove the checked attribute of the radio button from the browser via the inspect element tool, it will show error in PHP when the submit button will be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" checked="true"> 
   <label id="r">Red</label>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green">
   <label id="g">Green</label>
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
   <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['add']))
   {
       if(isset($_POST['colors']))
       {
            $colorVal = $_POST['colors'];
           echo "$colorVal";
       }
   }
?>
```

Defines a submit button (for submitting the form) by making its type as SUBMIT

```
<input type="submit">
```

> The `<input type="button">` defines a clickable button (mostly used with
>   a JavaScript to activate a script).

Also, you have a syntax error for $_POST

Answer (score 2):

The type of your `Add` button must be `submit` also the `Clear` button has to be `reset`.
By the way that `$POST['colors']` needs to be `$_POST['colors']`.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" checked="true"> 
    <label id="r">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green">
    <label id="g">Green</label>

    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['colors'])) {
        $colorVal = $_POST['colors'];
        echo "$colorVal";
    }
}
?>
```

**Update:** (the reset button works as expected)

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" checked="true"> 
    <label id="r">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green">
    <label id="g">Green</label>

    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Comment: type="reset" it doesn't work, my echo doesn't clear the output.

Comment: @Artemis It has to work or you've forgotten to use the `<form>` tag.

Comment: @Artemis By the way the Clear button in the accepted answer is not valid.